# Is it possible to use nested links in Markdown -> to use in github

Tags: github, hyperlink, nested, markdown

I would like to find a way to use nested url links in markdown (or a simple code) to be able to:

- have a reference file in GitHub (reference.md) containing all the links that I cite several times in several *.md files in my repository. This to be able to correct broken links in one place without having to crosscheck all my files. Is this possible?

ex:

- reference.md file contains: `[citat1]:url`
- files 1.md...2.md..n.md contain code meaning something like: `[citat1](lookup and use the url given in reference.md)`

so if I click on `citat1` on the generated webpage from the different files 1...2 the link would be active and redirect me to the appropriate url.

Anyone can help or point in the right direction? thanks

Comment: No, this is not possible. I have seen custom Markdown extensions which some people have created for that sort of thing, but GitHub would not let you run your custom code on their site, so that is not an option.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, then I can stop to look for a how to solution.